# React components not rendering from dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, babeljs

I'm following the [React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) and building a React/Express app based on the repository in [github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial).

In the tutorials `index.html` all React dependenices are listed in this file as:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/example.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      // To get started with this tutorial running your own code, simply remove
      // the script tag loading scripts/example.js and start writing code here.
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However when I add the React packages I need into the package.json dependencies as:

```
{
  "name": "react_example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple react example",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "babel-standalone": "^6.17.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

I then include these in the `example.js` file as:

```
require('babel-standalone');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var axios = require('axios');
```

Nothing is rendered and in the browser console I get an error:

`example.js:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Where line 19 is:

`<div className="comment">`

I'm a novice with React and want to find out how I can render React components.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together the steps to get [React working with Webpack](http://vijayt.com/post/minimal-scaffolding-react-webpack/). If you follow the article, you will get a React application with minimal scaffolding.

babel-core is required for babel to work. babel-preset-react is for JSX compilation. babel-preset-es2015 is for transpilation from es6 to es5. babel-loader is required for webpack to build.

In your case, most likely babel-preset-react or equivalent script is not available for compiling JSX to JS.

Comment: if you have express server, maybe a webpack build should be sufficient. there is no need for webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two methods of development together in one. The example mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) is compiling all JSX syntax and on the fly in the browser and contains compiled `react` scripts as below

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
```

In the `example.js` you are not required to `require` these as you can see [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/public/scripts/example.js) in which you have written import statements.

```
require('babel-standalone');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var axios = require('axios');
```

They have used `npm` to run a simple node server(and not to compile react/babel) that can serve as simple API endpoint. This example is only to learn react with minimal setup and hence i don't suggest you to use it to build any application.

I hope you are trying to use `npm` as the package manager/development environment and start developing. For this there are lots of tutorials like [this](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack).

**EDIT**

Remove the below scripts and i hope it should start rendering

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2**

Change you index.html to something similar to below

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>React Tutorial</title>
      <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/example.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: that's the problem I'm having I'm trying to use NPM to install packages not the first method. But this still doesn't render thr React components.

Comment: That is what I had done but the React components do not render.

Comment: provide a pastebin link of your generated `example.js` file and your `index.html`

Comment: Apart from the imported statements in example.js the index.html and example.js are cloned from the [react tutorial repository](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks but that's what I had done already and it still does not work.

Comment: you should provide a pastebin link of your generated example.js file and your index.html

Comment: Where would the generated files be?

Comment: you are again trying to combine two methods of development by using `babel-standalone` to transpile all at browser, but in this case you cannot `require` files on a browser. Browsers dont support `require` statement yet. A server side transpiler like `babel` with a server like `webpack` or `browsify` can transiple the code and send it to your browser. You should not follow this example to develop if you are gonna use npm pacakages and require them or find a good mentor to correct this code and explain it.

Comment: You are getting the error `<` because, the browser is expecting a JS while the file contains HTML tags which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Ok so I need to webpack